# For an implicit function $y(x+y)^2=x$ find $\int{dx\over x+3y}$

Tags: integration

If y is implicit differentiable function of $x$ such that $y(x+y)^2 = x$.

Then find the integral $$\int{dx\over x+3y}$$

I have tried using differential equation part and found the relation between dx and dy but the final integration part is where I’m stuck.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Exy8k.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE, take a [tour]. Please do not use images for critical part of your question. Images are not searchable and cannot be read by some, as people that use screen readers. $\quad$ I suggest you to copy your steps using the Mathjax format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
{dy\over dx}&={1-2y(x+y)\over (x+y)(x+3y)}\\
\Rightarrow1+{dy\over dx}&={1+(x+y)^2\over (x+y)(x+3y)}
\end{align}
$$

Let $x+y=t$

$$
{dt\over dx}={1+t^2\over t(x+3y)}\\
\Rightarrow \int{tdt\over 1+t^2}=\int{dx\over x+3y}
$$

So $$\int {dx\over x+3y}={1\over2}ln(1+(x+y)^2)+C$$

Comment: WTA 37 was easy